# How to convert a numeric value in a Object to String to be sent in an Email Task?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, expression, etl

I'm trying to send an e-mail with values read from the database.

So I have an Execute SQL task that Selects data from the db, the values are returned into an Object Variable, after that I have a Foreach Row in Object loop container that sends an e-mail to the specific e-mail with specific fields hat are on the Object variable. This all works well until we get into the numeric value and date value. I can't seem to CAST or TURN the values into STRING.I've tried some solutions around the internet but none seem to work.

The error I get is:

> Expression cannot be evaluated

```
"Type:" + @[User::vType]  + "Cost:" +  (DT_WSTR, @[User::vCost] )
((DT_R8)LEFT(@[User::vCost],9) * (RIGHT(@[User::vCost],1) == "-" ? -1 : 1)/100.0)
```

I've tried both of these solutions but they don't seem to work. I'm stuck at the moment without any ideas on how to fix this.

Does anybody have any ideas on how to fix this, or any fixes?

Comment: (DT_WSTR,100) @[User::vCost]

Answer (score 0):

You have to be precisely clear on what you are casting. This will do it for you:

```
(DT_WSTR,100) @[User::vCost]
```